# Counting non-repetitive occurrence

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int num2[ ]={100,101,101,102,103,104,104,105,106,106,106,107,107,108,108,108,108,109,109,110};
int num3[ ]={1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1015,1015,1015,1015,1015,107,107,107,107,107,107,107};
```

From the above two arrays what I have to do is to count the number of occurrences of different numbers from the array `num2`.  The number of different occurrences would be based on the array `num3`.

For example:  in the `num3[16]`, the first element [0] is `1010` and up to 8th position of the array `num1`, the element `1010` is the same. Therefore we would have to count occurance of different number in `num2` for the element `1010`. 
So for the `1010` element in the `num3`, we have different number occurrence in `num2` is  6. These different numbers in `num2`  are `100,101,102,103,104,105`.

For the next entry in `num3`, it has to be a  different number than the first one (1010). Therefore total different entry in `num2`is 2 for the corresponding array element in `num3` 1015.  and they are = `106,107`  in the `num2` array

If I was doing the counting the same number of occurrences I could have done easily like this:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
 int num2[]={100,101,101,102,103,104,104,105,106,106,106,107,107,108,108,108,108,109,109,110};

    int n = sizeof(num2) / sizeof(num2[0]); 
    cout << "Number of times 101 appears : "
         << count(num2, num2 + n, 101); 

    return 0; 
}
```

But the problem is different since I would have to follow the array `num3` and count the nonrepetitive occurrence in `num2` for the nonrepetitive elements in `num3`.

Comment: consider `std::unique` or `std::unique_copy` to remove the repeated occurrences and then `std::count` to count occurrences. of course if you just consider one value there are also ways to do it without the pre-processing step of `std::unique`

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;` - No. Don't *ever* do that. You are depending on a specific implementations header being available and it's a header that pulls in *everything*, and then you add on "using namespace std" and now all good names are in use. Please, please don't *ever* do that in production code. Not even in test code.

Comment: Wow, I answered 4 minutes before closing. Since the new closing rules have been introduced, people must be really fast in answering, before the guardians of the grail shoot . . .

Comment: I see the rules are very strict here. I fixed the array size. I hope the flag will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drafted one of many possible solutions. I use C++ and not C, so, no plain C-Style arrays. But, the used algorithm will of course work also for C-Style arrays.

Please note:  Your input data is wrong. You created an array with 16 values, but the initializer list is 20 values long.

I am using a `std::vector` for my solution.

First we iterate over num3 from start to end. We set the initial "start"-index to 0. Then, we compare the ith element with the ith+1 element. As long as they are equal, we increment the i-index. If a next, none equal value is found, then i has the index of the new differing value.

To count the different values from num2, we use a special property of `std::set`. `std::set` can only contain unique or distinct values. So, we try to put all values from num2 into the `std::set`. But only distinct values will be added. Values, which are already in the `std::set`, will be discarded. We have "start" and "i" and using the `std::set`'s range constructor to fill it.

And for getting the result, we just need to count the elements in `std::set`, using its `size()` function.

At the end, we set a new start value, and continue. Simple solution, but works.

Please see:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <iterator>
#include <iomanip>

std::vector<int> num2{ 100,101,101,102,103,104,104,105,106,106,106,107,107,108,108,108,108,109,109,110 };
std::vector<int> num3{ 1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1010,1015,1015,1015,1015,1015,107,107,107,107,107,107,107 };

int main() {

    // Check for sufficent sizes of the vector
    if (num2.size() >= num3.size()) {
        // Initial start value. We will search at the begin of num3
        size_t start{ 0 };
        while (start < num3.size()) {

            // Set i = equal to current start value. So, search at the beginning of the next unequal number
            size_t i{ start };
            // Find the next non matching value
            while (i < (num3.size() - 1) && (num3[i] == num3[i + 1])) ++i;

            // Copy all values from num 2 in a std::set, which can only contain distinct values
            std::set<int> values(std::next(num2.begin(), start), std::next(num2.begin(), i));

            // Print result. Show number of distinct values
            std::cout << "\n" << std::setw(2) << values.size() << " -> " << std::setw(5) << num3[i] << " --> ";
            std::copy(values.begin(), values.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

            // Evaluate next identical values from num3
            start = ++i;
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n***** Error: num2 too short\n";

    return 0;
}
```